# Improving performance of ListView.builder with nested FutureBuilders

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

The ListView.builder of my widget is really laggy and slow when scrolling, especially in debug mode.

```dart
class SongsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SongsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final songsProvider = Provider.of<Songs>(context, listen: false);
    final songs = songsProvider.getSongs();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ListView.builder(
          primary: true,
          itemCount: songs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
              future: Future.wait([
                songsProvider.getTags(songs[index]),
                songsProvider.getArtwork(songs[index]),
              ]),
              builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return snapshot.data![1] != null
                      ? ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data![0].title ?? 'Unknown'),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data![0].artist ?? 'Unknown'),
                          leading: ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                              child: Image.memory(
                                snapshot.data![1],
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              )),
                        )
                      : ListTile(
                          title: Text(songs[index]),
                          subtitle: const Text('Unknown'),
                          leading: const CircleAvatar(
                            child: Icon(Iconsax.music5),
                          ),
                        );
                } else {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(songs[index]),
                    subtitle: const Text('Unknown'),
                    leading: const CircleAvatar(
                      child: Icon(Iconsax.music5),
                    ),
                  );
                }
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a possible way to improve the performance? My guess is that the FutureBuilders are slowing down the performance but I could be wrong.

**EDIT:** I've rearranged the code and now I see a small improvement. But it's still not so smooth.

Comment: You should load your future list before widget build and then put result to the list builder.

Comment: do not call `songs.getSongs()` multiple times - just call it once and store the result somewhere, also what do you see if you add some `print` statements as the first line in both `builder:` callbacks?

Comment: @pskink I thought of doing that but `songs` is a provider and so I need `context`. When I put some `print` statements on the `builder` callbacks I've noticed that they get called many times.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the future function to wait for the result, and as soon as it produces the result it calls the builder function where you build the widget.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:audiotagger/models/tag.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iconsax/iconsax.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:taggr/providers/songs.dart';

class SongsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SongsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final songs = Provider.of<Songs>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: songs.getTags(songs.getSongs()),
            builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<Tag?> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                          title: Text(snapshot.data[index]!.title!),
                          subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[index]!.artist!),
                          leading: FutureBuilder(
                            future: songs.getArtwork(songs.getSongs()[index]
                                .path),
                            builder: (ctx, AsyncSnapshot<
                                Uint8List?> artworkSnapshot) {
                              if (artworkSnapshot.hasData) {
                                return ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                  child: Image.memory(artworkSnapshot.data!),
                                );
                              } else {
                                return const CircleAvatar(
                                  child: Icon(Iconsax.music5),
                                );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const Text('n');
              }
            },
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```